# paste function giving different results in R console and shiny

Tags: r, shiny, paste

In R, to append "1" to all values of a column I use the following

```
data[,col] =  paste(data[,col], "1", sep = "_")
```

and this gives me great results.
However, the same is not happening when I try to do it inside Shiny. Sorry for not being able to share a reproducible code. But the code that I am using in shiny is as follows.

```
proc_filt_good = reactive({

   proc_filt_good[,1] =  paste(proc_filt_good[,1], "1", sep = "_")
})
```

This is giving me something as follows.

```
c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 17, 17, 17, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26,
26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28,
28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36,
42, 42, 54, 54, 60, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 127, 127, 127, 127, 128, 128,
128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128)_1
```

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: To me this looks like you are redefining the vector as a reactive expression at the same time that you are using it as a vector. I would consider just naming your reactive expression something else and seeing if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @be_green - I tried that as well but to no avail.. After using the paste on a different dataframe, I copied it to the reactive element. But the problem still persisted.

Comment: Based on the output you're seeing I'd guess that the data is actually subtly different in the two cases somehow. Specifically, it looks like what you're getting is what would happen if `proc_filt_goodp,1]` were actually a list. But it's impossible for me to confirm this with a reproducible example.